# Showing selecting text in a WPF TextBox without ever giving focus to it

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, selection

There are similar questions out there like this, however, they all end up giving focus to the textbox, which is exactly what I don't want.

Basically, I'm making a modeless replace dialog, and I want to be able to select the text behind it without ever giving my textbox focus. Now, I have set the `IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled` already, which makes it show, but I have to give focus to the box before it will show the first selection. After that I can change the selection and it will show without giving focus.

Note that the main reason I want to never give focus to the textbox is because it causes a flash when the focus is lost and regained. If that can be avoided, it will work just as well.

This is what I'm using which will cause the flash

```
TextContent.Select(start_idx, len);
TextContent.Focus();
this.Focus();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to this is where you mentioned "After that I can change the selection and it will show without giving focus".

I created a test app that recreated the flashing issue. After InitializeComponent() in the parent form, I created a dummy selection, focused the TextBox then shifted the focus to something else. Something like this:

```
TextContent.Select(0, 0);
TextContent.Focus();
Button1.Focus();
```

Then when the modeless dialog is launched and the selection changed on the TextBox it will work without having to give focus to the TextBox and hence avoid the flashing on the first selection.

Comment: I've tried that, and it doesn't work. It does if I do `TextContent.Select(0, 1)`, but a `(0, 0)` doesn't seem to work for me. Also, if I edit while the dialog is open, then the selection is lost, and if I hit "Find", then I have to refocus `TextContent` to see the new selection.

Comment: That's odd, (0,0) does the trick for me, but regardless as you say, it doesn't deal with edits. I'll keep thinking!